# Why are Dirac spinor representations defined as a projection onto the first factor?

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, mathematical-physics, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

Let $\mathbb{C}l(n)$ denote the Clifford algebra over $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the standard bilinear form. Then
$$\mathbb{C}l(n) \cong \begin{cases} \text{End}(\mathbb{C}^N) \quad n \text{ is even}\\ \text{End}(\mathbb{C}^N) \oplus \text{End}(\mathbb{C}^N) \quad n \text{ is odd}\end{cases} \tag{1}$$
where the value of $N$ depends on both the value of $n$ and if $n$ is even or odd. In Hamilton's *Mathematical Gauge Theory* he defines the vector space of Dirac spinors as $\mathbb{C}^N$ and the Dirac spinor representation of the complex Clifford algebra
$$\rho: \mathbb{C}l(n) \rightarrow \text{End}(\mathbb{C}^N) \tag{2}$$
by (1) if $n$ is even and by
$$\mathbb{C}l(n) \xrightarrow{\cong}\text{End}(\mathbb{C}^N) \oplus \text{End}(\mathbb{C}^N) \xrightarrow{\pi_1} \text{End}(\mathbb{C}^N) \tag{3}$$
if $n$ is odd. Here $\pi_1$ is the projection onto the first factor. This defines Dirac spinors.

Why do we project onto the first factor in (3) if $n$ is odd? Wouldn't the direct product in (1) be enough to define a representation (2)?

Comment: I don't understand your second question. The codomain of a representation is $\operatorname{End}(\mathbb{C}^N)$. Without projecting, we have a map $\mathbb{C}l(n) \to \operatorname{End}(\mathbb{C}^N)\oplus\operatorname{End}(\mathbb{C}^N)$ which is not a representation.

Comment: A map $\mathbb{C}l(n)\to\text{End}(\mathbb{C}^N)\oplus\text{End}(\mathbb{C}^N)$ would induce a representation $\mathbb{C}l(n)\to\text{End}(\mathbb{C}^{2N})$. However, this representation would not be irreducible. After projecting to the first or second fator, we get irreducible representations, and they are isomorphic. So it does not matter which factor is projected onto, in the end.

Comment: @QuaereVerum Thank you. So the only reason we project onto either of the two factors is to get an irreducible representation?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes you are right, sorry I did not word that well. I did not understand why we project onto the first factor. It seems arbitrary.

Comment: I'll refer to this article: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/spin+representation. TLDR: The even representation splits into two inequivalent irreducible representations. The odd representation splits into two equivalent irreducible representations, and so we can "throw one away" by projecting onto one summand. Because yes, we only care about the irreducible representations.

Comment: @QuaereVerum Thank you.